# What's the best way to persist this type of data (nested dictionaries) in python?

Tags: python, database, storage, storing-data

I have 70GB+ data which needs to be persisted, one such way to easily represent this data is:

```
{Name of entity :
    {type of document:
        {date :
            [text, score, score2, embedding, grouping (could be None), predicted class, manual class (could be non)]
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the data consists of a named entity, which optionally belongs to a grouping. Each entity puts out different types of documents every 3 weeks. Foreach document, we collect it, assign it two different scores, and then store it with the date and embedding for a downstream task.

Right now, this is done as follows:
we have several folders which each represent the different types of documents, and the text is stored in .jsons which are keyed {date : text}:

```
doc_type1/entity1.json, ...
doc_type2/entity1.json, ...
```

we then have a .csv which maps each entity name to its grouping:

| entity name | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| entity1 | C++ |
| entity2 | (None) |
| entity3 | python |

Then we have another .csv which maps each individual document to its scores:

| doc name | scores |
| --- | --- |
| entity1_date_type | (1,3) |
| entity2_date_type | (2,3) |
| entity3_date_type | (0,2) |

Scores are likely to change every time we refine our method, we may eventually add more groupings or associate those entities which have not yet been added to a grouping. Each entity adds new text every once in a while, and the embedding is likely to change as well. As our method gets more advanced, we may or may not change the predicted class, and our raters may manually assign a datapoint a class.

At this point, the way we store our data has kind of ballooned in complexity and is starting to hinder progress. Is there any python-accessible, more efficient way to store this type of data?

Comment: Something like a database?

Comment: Yeah. But I'm trying to find out what databases lend themselves to this type of storage. A cursory search still doesn't say what might be the best way to store this type of data.